# Multicurrency strategy - Blotter & Quantstrat

Tags: r, quantstrat, blotter, financialinstrument

I would want to rebound on this thread

http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Multi-currency-example-for-blotter-td1692132.html

Basically, I'm backtesting a strategy using quantstrat where I have instruments in several currencies but I would want an aggregate reporting in USD (i.e. account and portfolios in USD)

For simplification purpose, let's say i'm backtesting a simple 20-120 MA crossover strategy, on BRENT futures (in EUR), but i would want to have my PnL in USD.

I will try to provide all the necessary info as Joshua Ulrich is strict on reproducible examples and he is right.

## My function to import csv file and clean data

```
getdata <- function(ticker){

  d <- read.csv(ticker, header=TRUE, sep = ",")
  d[,1] <- as.Date(as.character(d[,1]), tz ="GMT", format="%m/%d/%Y")
  d <- as.xts(d[,-1], order.by =d[,1] )
  colnames(d) <- c("Open","High","Low","Close")
  return(d)
  }

BRENT <- getdata("BRENT.csv")
EURUSD<- getdata("EURUSD.csv")
```

The data is available here

https://gist.github.com/nbmacro

Once I have imported my BRENT.csv witht the right format , I set up the instruments

```
currency(c("USD","EUR",))
exchange_rate(c("EURUSD"),"USD")  
future("BRENT",currency = "EUR",tick_size = 0.01,multiplier = 1000)
```

So I have my data imported, instruments setted up, I can run the usual quantstrat code.

```
symbols <- c("BRENT")
Sys.setenv(TZ="GMT")
rm(list = ls(.blotter), envir = .blotter)

#Set up environment
if (!exists('.blotter')) .blotter <- new.env()
if(!exists('.strategy')) .strategy <- new.env()
if(!exists('.instrument')) .instrument <- new.env()


start.date <- min(index(symbols))+50      #1ere date du jeu de donnée
end.date <- Sys.Date()-5      #dernière date du jeu de donnée
initial.capital <- 0      #Capital de départ
MAcrossover <- strategy("MAcrossover")
portfolio.st <- account.st <- strat.st <- "MAcrossover"

initPortf(portfolio.st,        #nom du book
          symbols = symbols,  #list des instruments
          currency='USD') 

initAcct(account.st,                 #nom du compte
         portfolios = portfolio.st,  #nom du portfeuille rattaché au compte
         # initDate = init.date,       #date de départ du compte
         currency = "USD",           #devise du compte
         initEq = initial.capital)   #capital de départ du compte

initOrders(portfolio.st, 
           symbols = symbols)    

strategy("MAcrossover",store = TRUE)

#Parametres
ma1 <- 20
ma2 <- 120
maxpos <- 1
tradesize <- 1
#position limit
addPosLimit("MAcrossover", symbols, maxpos = maxpos, timestamp = start(BRENT)-1)

#preparation indicateurs
for(symbol in symbols){

  x=get(symbol)
  x$MA1 <- SMA(Cl(x),n=ma1)
  x$MA2 <- SMA(Cl(x),n=ma2)
  assign(symbol,x)
}

#Signal
add.signal("MAcrossover",                #nom de la strategie
           name="sigCrossover",      #type de signal
           arguments = list(columns =c("MA1","MA2"), #liste des colonnes pour déterminer le signal
                            relationship="gt"),   #type de relation du signal (sup ou égal, sup, inférieur etc..)
           label = "long")        #label de la colonne du signal

add.signal("MAcrossover",                #nom de la strategie
           name="sigCrossover",      #type de signal
           arguments = list(columns =c("MA1","MA2"), #liste des colonnes pour déterminer le signal
                            relationship="lt"),   #type de relation du signal (sup ou égal, sup, inférieur etc..)
           label = "short")        #label de la colonne du signal

add.signal("MAcrossover",                #nom de la strategie
           name="sigCrossover",      #type de signal
           arguments = list(columns =c("MA1","MA2"), #liste des colonnes pour déterminer le signal
                            relationship="lt"),   #type de relation du signal (sup ou égal, sup, inférieur etc..)
           label = "exitlong")        #label de la colonne du signal

add.signal("MAcrossover",                #nom de la strategie
           name="sigCrossover",      #type de signal
           arguments = list(columns =c("MA1","MA2"), #liste des colonnes pour déterminer le signal
                            relationship="gt"),   #type de relation du signal (sup ou égal, sup, inférieur etc..)
           label = "exitshort")        #label de la colonne du signal


#Rules
add.rule("MAcrossover",                               #nom de la strategie 
         name = "ruleSignal",                      #
         arguments = list(sigcol ="long",          #nom de la colonne à vérifier
                          sigval = TRUE,           #Application de la règle si signal
                          orderqty=tradesize,        #taille de l'ordre
                          osFUN = osMaxPos,
                          prefer = "Close",
                          replace = FALSE,
                          ordertype = "market",    #type d'ordre
                          orderside ="long"),   #sens
         type = "enter",          #ouverture ou fermeture de pose
         label = "enterlongcrossover")    #label si exécution

add.rule("MAcrossover",                                  #nom de la strategie 
         name = "ruleSignal",                      #
         arguments = list(sigcol ="short",          #nom de la colonne à vérifier
                          sigval = TRUE,           #Application de la règle si signal
                          orderqty="all",        #taille de l'ordre
                          replace = FALSE,
                          ordertype = "market",    #type d'ordre
                          orderside ="long"),   #sens
         type = "exit",          #ouverture ou fermeture de pose
         label = "exitlongcrossover")    #label si exécution

add.rule("MAcrossover",                                  #nom de la strategie 
         name = "ruleSignal",                      #
         arguments = list(sigcol ="short",          #nom de la colonne à vérifier
                          sigval = TRUE,           #Application de la règle si signal
                          orderqty=-tradesize,#taille de l'ordre
                          replace = FALSE,
                          prefer = "Close",
                          osFUN = osMaxPos,
                          ordertype = "market",    #type d'ordre
                          orderside ="short"),   #sens
         type = "enter",          #ouverture ou fermeture de pose
         label = "Entershort")    #label si exécution

add.rule("MAcrossover",                                  #nom de la strategie 
         name = "ruleSignal",                      #
         arguments = list(sigcol ="long",          #nom de la colonne à vérifier
                          sigval = TRUE,           #Application de la règle si signal
                          orderqty="all",        #taille de l'ordre
                          replace = FALSE,
                          ordertype = "market",    #type d'ordre
                          orderside ="short"),   #sens
         type = "exit",          #ouverture ou fermeture de pose
         label = "exitshortcrossover")    #label si exécution

out <- applyStrategy("MAcrossover", portfolios = portfolio.st)

updatePortf("MAcrossover")
updateAcct("MAcrossover")
updateEndEq("MAcrossover")
```

Basically, the model trades correctly. 
As an example to illustrate my point, Let's take the first trade
The model goes long on 2002-03-06 at 22.72. The next day's close is 23.3. 
So the Pnl in EUR should be (23.3-22.72)*1000 (multiplier) = 580€.
On the 2002-03-07, the EURUSD's Close is 0.8822 so the USD's Pnl should be 580*0.8822 = 511.67 USD.

Interestingly, when i set the future Brent with currency = EUR

```
future("BRENT",currency = "EUR",tick_size = 0.01,multiplier = 1000)
```

I get a PnL on the 2002-03-07 at 643.45

And when i set the future Brent with currency = USD

I get a PnL on the 2002-03-07 at 580

That's not logical. And the implicit EURUSD is (580/643) = 0.90 vs a correct rate of 0.8822.

So my question is
- Can we handle several currencies ? 
- If yes, where am I wrong ?

Thanks a lot in advance,

Nicolas.